# Recursive Backtracking to Display a List of Words

Tags: java, string, list, recursion

I'm working on an Anagram Finder program. One of the methods I'm writing introduces the concept of **recursive backtracking** which I'm completely new to. I'm hoping to get some suggestions of how this works/how to make it work.

I'm trying to implement recursive backtracking in order to display a list of words from a dictionary text file to form anagrams for an input phrase. Here's what I have so far:

```
public void printAnagrams(String phrase, int max, List<List<String>> anagrams) {
    if (anagrams == null) { 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(); 
    } else if (max != 0) {
        System.out.println("...");
    } else 
        System.out.println("...");
    for (List<String> element : anagrams)
        System.out.println(anagrams);
}// End of printAnagram method
```

If max > 0, only combination of max words or less are displayed.
Since the program is pretty long, the background info is listed in the links below.

AnagramFinder class: [raw code](http://pastebin.com/KQSepSJH)

Client class:  [raw code](http://pastebin.com/C76J7UcW)

**This is the expected results:**

File name? dict2.txt

Phrase to Scramble? off course

All words found in "off course":
[core, course, cs, cure, for, force, forces, four, of, off, offer, offers, or, our, ours, re, score, so, source, suffer, sure, us, use, user]

Max words to include (Enter for no max)? 3

[core, off, us]

[core, us, off]

[course, off]

[cure, off, so]

[cure, so, off]

[force, of, us]

[force, us, of]

[of, force, us]

[of, us, force]

[off, core, us]

[off, course]

[off, cure, so]

[off, so, cure]

[off, source]

[off, us, core]

[so, cure, off]

[so, off, cure]

[source, off]

[us, core, off]

[us, force, of]

[us, of, force]

[us, off, core]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a linkedlist instead of list> it's better  and easier to understand